# How do I populate a Form View with business object and stored procedure? (DataSource objects/DataBound Controls)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I successfully used a business object, a stored procedure and struct to populate a page with a list of Text Box controls to display and allow editing for some customer details data. I individually assigned each Text Box control to a value from the struct.

I then successfully used a SqlDataSource to populate a Form View to display the same customer details data.

I now want to use the bus object, stored procedure and struct (or other object) to display the customer details data in a Form View.

Here is how I call the business object to get the data and return it into a struct in the Load event of the Customer Details page:

```
 CustomerDetailsStruct cd = CustomerDetailsAccess.GetCustomerDetails(customerId);
```

How do I tell the Form View to use the struct?
Or, do I need to retrieve the data into a different object?

Here is the code from the page where I am displaying the Customer Details data when I initially used a SqlDataSource:

```
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" ForeColor="#333333">
```

I see that there is a DataSource property avaialable. The example on this MSDN page uses a DataSet.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx
I also read about the ObjectDataSource at MSDN.

Please let me know if I need to provide more details or more code.

I would also like to ask a broader question:
Can someone recommend a good book or website that can explain DataSource objects and DataBound controls and how to pair them up? I am currently going through a book that has some good examples of how to do some things. But, is there a good reference guide out there to data binding?

---

Here is more of my  Form View.

TheKingDave:
I don't have a DataSource or DataSourceID property because I don't know how to use the struct or an alternate object as my data source in the Page_Load event, which is my main question. I am getting the struct here in the Page_Load event. I think I need to make it the data source here somehow:

```
                // Get the Customer Details data with the business object.
        CustomerDetailsStruct cd = CustomerDetailsAccess.GetCustomerDetails(customerId);
```

Here is the start of the EditItemTemplate.
I copied/pasted it from the code in the Form View that used the SqlDataSource so I wouldn't have to recreate the table. It is just a table with Text Box Controls in the EditItemTemplate and labels in the ItemItemplate.

```
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"  CellPadding="4"  ForeColor="#333333">
<FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
<EditItemTemplate>

    <table cellpadding="5" class="UserDetailsTable">       
   <tr>
        <td class="UserDetailsTitleCell">Address1:</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Address1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address1") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox></td>
   </tr>
```

Here is the start of the Item Template:

```
        <ItemTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="5" class="UserDetailsTable">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Customer Details:</th> 
</tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="UserDetailsTitleCell">Address1:</td>
    <td class="UserDetailsTitleCell"><asp:Label ID="Address1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address1") %>'></asp:Label></td> 
    </tr>
```

Need more/something else?

Comment: You need to add a datasource for your formview. You can actually do this through the wizard to get an example. You then connect the datasource to whatever code eventually gets the data...

Comment: Can you post the complete code? You posted only the FormView opening tag. Did you define any inner templates for it? And where is that "SqlDataSource1" datasource linked to the formview?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CustomerDetailsStruct cd = CustomerDetailsAccess.GetCustomerDetails(customerId);

//FormView DataSource has to be IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource
List<CustomerDetailsStruct> list = new List<CustomerDetailsStruct>();
list.Add(cd);
FormView.DataSource = list;

//Choose the proper mode (templates have to be defined) 
FormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
FormView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Mt. Schneiders: I tried your code. I am getting error messages on the curly brackets that say that semicolons are expected.

Comment: Mt. Schneiders: Thanks for all your help. That code did not work either. It stopped on the first TextBox control (see first chunk of code above) and says that: "DataBinding: 'CustomerDetailsStruct' does not contain a property with the name 'Address1'." My struct does have Address1 as the first container. Thanks, again for your help. I am going to try a different approach to this page.